# Spring, Hibernate Insert English data but SQL Server display china character

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I'm trying to insert data in Main class to Department table with Hibernate in Java Spring project the ID column is set identity, but when I insert data is English SQL server display some china character. This is my main class

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Department de = new Department("afsad");
    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

    try {

        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(de);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if(session.getTransaction().isActive()){
        session.getTransaction().rollback();}
   e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This is my hibernate config

```
             <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=w</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">a</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">111</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
    <mapping resource="Entity/Department.hbm.xml"/>
```

This is hbm.xml file of Department I set generator class="identity" because when generator class="assigned"  i can't insert

```
         <class name="Entity.Department" table="Department" schema="dbo" catalog="wix" optimistic-lock="version">
    <id name="departId" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="Depart_Id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="departName" type="serializable">
        <column name="Depart_Name" />
    </property>
    <set name="employees" table="Employee" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="Depart_Id" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="Entity.Employee" />
    </set>
</class>
```

And the Department class

```
        public class Department  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private int departId;
 private Serializable departName;
 private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<Employee>(0);

public Department() {
}

public Department(Serializable departName) {
    this.departName = departName;
}


public Department(int departId) {
    this.departId = departId;
}
public Department(int departId, Serializable departName, Set<Employee> employees) {
   this.departId = departId;
   this.departName = departName;
   this.employees = employees;
}

public int getDepartId() {
    return this.departId;
}

public void setDepartId(int departId) {
    this.departId = departId;
}
public Serializable getDepartName() {
    return this.departName;
}

public void setDepartName(Serializable departName) {
    this.departName = departName;
}
```

Any one know about this,any suggest

Comment: Can you show the data that is inserted? Query as well as the result

Comment: ok this one is Hibernate: insert into a.dbo.Department (Depart_Name) values (test)
and the data i got is Ԁt琄獥t

Comment: And what data is passed into the query?

Comment: i passed String "test" the table just have 2 column is ID and Name when id i set identity just have name left

Comment: But what passed hibernate into the query? the `?` must have been repalced by something and I want to know by what

Comment: i create an object from class Department then passed a name to it in main class i believed i passed object sorry for bad english

Comment: I know that you do that, but hibernate creates plain SQL querys to insert the data and in  such a query you can't pass an object. Have a look at hibernate TRACE logging and find out what value is passed into the query